# debug php script row by row

Tags: php, debugging

I already know all the common ways to display errors in php and I would ask something different.
I would know if it's possible to execute a php script from console and execute it row by row showing on console

- the php code row of the code executed in that moment

So I could see exactly when the code fail and which is the code generating the error.

Comment: 2 follow up questions: 1) are you open to doing this in conjunction with an IDE and 2) what is your development environment

Comment: no IDE, testing the script from Linux console

Comment: Why not use xDebug for this, or any other debugger? And yes, that's perfectly possible, I've done it multiple times today

Answer (score 1):

If you can use composer dependencies then something like
https://github.com/tacnoman/dephpugger
may provide what you need.